# Fiddle with jaydata and kendoui grid MVVM - filter doesn't work

Tags: kendo-ui, jaydata

The following fiddle is using jaydata and kendoui grid MVVM.  The data loads nicely but filtering does not work.  Why?

Will kendoui and jaydata combination be able to use the kendoui grid grouping functionality any time soon?

http://jsfiddle.net/t316/4n62B/9/

```
<div id="airportGrid" data-kendo-role="grid" data-kendo-sortable="true" data-kendo-pageable="true" data-kendo-page-size="25" data-kendo-editable="true" data-kendo-filterable="true"  data-kendo-columns='["id", "Abbrev", "Name"]' data-kendo-bind="source: airports"></div>

kendo.ns = "kendo-";
$data.service("https://open.jaystack.net/c72e6c4b-27ba-49bb-9321-e167ed03d00b/6494690e-1d5f-418d-adca-0ac515b7b742/api/mydatabase/", function (factory, type) {
                var airportDB = factory();
                var vm = {airports:airportDB.Airport.asKendoDataSource()};
                kendo.bind($('#airportGrid'),vm);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering should work, please provide more info. First of all, you should either use initService or use onReady(). 
Also, please check the network traffic and paste the relevant part here.
If you see our examples with kendo then you can see filtering in action.
http://jaydata.org/examples/?tags=KendoUI